# How do I start b43 drivers on bootup?

Tags: wireless

So I followed instructions a tad late to get my wireless setup going.  I use the b43 drivers.  The problem is that if I restart the computer, it won't activate until I launch the terminal and use the "modprobe b43" command.  Anyway that I can get it to start so I won't need to use it?

Comment: Have you the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package installed?

Comment: ya, I did the one for the STA method, but realized that I needed to look for b43 in the search using Ubuntu 11.10 instead of Broadcom.  Mine is the 4318 so I needed b43.  So I took it off as well as the source (since both were installed this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to `/etc/modules`

Just put the name eg `b43` **not** `sudo modprobe b43`

Comment: well stupid me, I woke up early, decided to look at it and added "foo" and my desktop would no longer show.  Instead, I would just get the options for opening windows and such, but not the time, the user name, etc.  So, I decided to restart from scratch, followed the b43 install correctly from the start (I didn't even notice the link it gives during setup), and so far, its been launching correctly without it.  I just don't know if I should give this as a correct answer for future use if part of the issue was user fault for not paying attention (and working in a groggy state of mind).

Comment: I'll mark that correct.  That makes me feel better :)